# Image Categorization with PHP

Tags: php, web

I'm building a website in PHP to share my comics.
I'd like to implement categorization to allow people to filter which comics they'd like to see.

The architecture is built around the filesystem, and not a database.

I've been thinking of two ways to do this:

1) Pass in user-selected category which changes the image path accordingly.
Would this require user sessioning/logging, I.E a much greater complexity?

2) Create a new "Comic Category" Page Template. 
So instead of passing in a user-selected category and filter images, the user would be brought to the new page template which displays only those selected images.

Any thoughts on this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Using filesystem. I updated my question.

Comment: Anyway, it is enough to pass GET param, which represents directory name and load all files from that directory using PHP. You'll need just one view(~ php page) for this.

Comment: I know you're using a filesystem architecture, but a database architecture is a lot more flexible in the long term. Suppose you want to change from "categories" to "tags" at some point? Or suppose a comic can live in multiple categories? Architecting around the file system is easy, but it also can result in painting yourself into a corner. Implementing your own database is a lot more work up front, but the payoff down the road is worth it, IMHO.

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits This is what I'm doing now,  but my issue is I've implemented pagination... and each time I change pages, it resets the selected category that's been passed in. How do I have it remember based on each user's unique selection?

Comment: @Growler Then you need to pass two GET variables each time. And modify pagination links to handle category parameter (<a href="index.php?cat=animals&page=2">2</a>). But database approach is much much better.

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits I started off implementing a database on my local WAMP server, but figured file management would be too complex down the road with thousands of files. Also, I didn't want to store the images as BLOBS in a database. Also, my hosting is from GoDaddy, I don't know if they give me access to their databases.

Comment: @Growler The best way is to store images in file system (possibly in different folders), and in database table store image name, category, tags and all connected data. Using BLOBS for gallery is definitely a bad idea. :)

Comment: @EdwardRuchevits Hey passing in cat and page worked! It now remembers it each time I navigate pages! Excellent! Question though, is 'cat' a predefined PHP variable for URLs? Also, while this works for me locally... how will this function when different users specify their own category?

Comment: @Growler 'cat' is an index in super global $_GET array. What you mean by specifying 'their own category'? You need to check category name is correct, because user can manually modify URL to set 'cat' value to something wrong. But the same situation with 'page'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both options are viable in terms of accomplishing your goal. However, the first option is a lot leaner in the sense that you do not need to implement a template for each comic category. Rather, you only need to create a single page and parse a `GET` parameter to determine the comic type. It is not complex as you will not need to store user sessions using this process.

For instance:

```
<?php
    $category = $_GET['c'];

    switch ($category) {
        case 'action':
            // handle action comics here
            break;
        case 'romance':
            // handle romance comics here
            break;
        case 'horror':
            // handle horror comics here
            break;
        default:
            // handle 404 here
    }
?>
```

In fact, this process may get even simpler if you were to implement this as a simple string manipulation, inserting `$category` where needed to adjust the image path.

Comment: But my question is: I've implemented pagination... and each time I change pages, it resets the selected category that's been passed in. How do I have it remember based on each user's unique selection?

Comment: You would pass the `c` GET parameter when the user changes pages. This keeps it in the URL, allowing for the website to recognize the category every time.

Comment: I don't have it working yet, but this is the guidance I was looking for. I'll give it a shot, but take the answer for now. Much appreciated- Dan